# Populating around 10 Gridviews using one data source ASP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to display data from one table to 10 gridviews based on a filter value (column).

Lets say colours. So pink grid view should only show items that have Pink in colour column.

At the moment I have one Gridview bound (in ASP) to one Datasource. I am  updating the datasource in codebehind.

Something like this:

```
 String selectcommand = Select * from table where subject = "Pink" 
 sqlDatasource1.SelectCommand= (selectcommand);
 mygv.Bind();
```

Obviously it would be a very bad idea to repeat the same code 10 times, one for each subject. Is there a better way of doing what I am after.

Main question is can I use the same datasorce with many gridviews after changing the colour?

**Solution One**

I bind all gridviews to one datasource and not bother about filtering by colour.

Then in gridview rowdatabound event of each gridview add something like this

```
if e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

   if e.Row.DataItem("colour") = "pink" then e.Row.visible = False
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: what is mygv...seems like some code is definitely missing

Comment: mygv. is a Gridview. This is just sudo code to give an idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: It is so sudo that we have no idea what you're trying to do ...

Comment: All those gridviews are defined in the asp page or build dynamically in code? Same for those sqlDatasources.

Comment: I have explained exactly what I am trying to do. 10 Gridview control, showing data from same table but to filter it based on a value in one of the columns.

Comment: @rene yeah all 10 will be defined in asp. I am open to suggestions on what would be the best solution. At the moment I only have one datasource in ASP. Ideally I want to reuse that to populate all the gridviews

Comment: What maybe works is returning all 10 results from that select statement. Your datasource will then be a dataset with 10 tables. Set the each gridview.Datasource to the sqlDatasource and set gridview.Datamember to the approriate datatable name. With a bit of luck that might fly.

Comment: Thanks that sounds good. How would I do that in practise?  How would the datasource become a dataset with 10 table?

Comment: how about replacing with a repeater which creates the the table markup from a single resultset which returns all the results, it can then use the colour field to decide what to do. Do you really need 10 interactable gridviews, or just 10 static HTML tables?

Comment: Yeah that probably work for me. I just need to display data and create my own interaction (Ability to delete rows.)

Comment: I dont really follow yet. Are you showing all the datagrids at the same time or one at a time ?

Comment: All will show at the same time. Each filter (colour) would have a section on the page. So say all red items on top left, black on top right, pink items all go below the red items and so on....

Answer (score 0):

You're right that duplicating the code would not be an ideal choice. However, as mentioned in the comments, you can make use of a repeater that loops over a grouped set of data (So you only query the database once), and then internally binds a GridView template.

The Aspx code could look like the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repColors" OnItemDataBound="repColors_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvColor" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The Repeater has an OnItemDataBound that will be used to find and bind the GridView inside of its ItemTemplate. This GridView is simple, but could be as complex as you need it to be for your use case.

The aspx.cs page will contain the code you need to load all of your subjects into the repeater and then bind the gridview using the OnItemDataBound event handler.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var data = GetColors();
    var dataByColors = data.ToLookup(c => c.Subject, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    repColors.DataSource = dataByColors;
    repColors.DataBind();
}

protected void repColors_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var gv = e.Item.FindControl("gvColor") as GridView;

        gv.DataSource = e.Item.DataItem;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}

public class Colors
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}

private IEnumerable<Colors> GetColors()
{
    yield return new Colors { Text = "Color1", Subject = "Blue" };
    yield return new Colors { Text = "Color2", Subject = "Pink" };
    yield return new Colors { Text = "Color3", Subject = "Blue" };
    yield return new Colors { Text = "Color4", Subject = "Red" };
    yield return new Colors { Text = "Color5", Subject = "Pink" };
}
```

Page_Load is used to fetch all of your data from the database. Then we use LINQ to group it by Subject which generates objects that look something like:

```
{"Blue": {Color1, Color3}}
{"Pink": {Color2, Color5}}
{"Red": {Color4}}
```

This is then bound to the repeater. The repeater's ItemDataBound event takes each individual data item (Which is a key and a list of colors) and binds it to the GridView that it's able to find in the Repeater template. The ILookup interface will by default enumerate over the list of items that it maintains. This allows it to be passed directly to the `GridView.DataSource` and we don't need to worry about trying to cast it to a List or anything.